# The question is regarding singly list in c++ and its operations, create and display

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have been trying to run the code for long now but it doesn't seem to run the way I want. There are some logical errors which I am unable to debug.
The code below runs fine with creating a linked list but it doesn't ask for the choice again which I had made using do while loop.It just abruptly ends the execution. Please help me fix this.

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct sll{
    char name[20];
    int rollno;
    struct sll *next;
}node;


node *create(node *first){
    node *a,*newnode;
    newnode=new sll;
    cout<<"--------------------------\n";
    cout<<"Enter Student Information\n";
    cout<<"Name- \t";
    cin>>newnode->name;
    cout<<"Roll No- ";
    cin>>newnode->rollno;
    cout<<"--------------------------\n";
    a->next=NULL;
    if(first==NULL)
        first=newnode;
    else{
        a=first;
        while(a->next!=NULL)
            a=a->next;
        a->next=newnode;
    }
    return newnode;
}
node *display(node *first){
    node *temp;
    if(first==NULL)
        cout<<"Empty List\n";
    else{
        temp=first;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            cout<<"Student Information\n";
            cout<<"--------------------------\n";
            cout<<"Name- ";
            cout<<temp->name;
            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<"Roll No- ";
            cout<<temp->rollno;
            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<"--------------------------\n";
            temp=temp->next;
        }   
    }
}
int main(){
    node *first=NULL;
    char n;
    int ch;
    do{
    cout<<"--------------------------\n";
    cout<<"Enter your choice\n";
    cout<<"1>Create LL\n2>Display\n";
    cout<<"--------------------------\n";
    cin>>ch;
    switch(ch){
        case 1: first=create(first);
                break;
        case 2: display(first);
                break;
//      case 3: insert_pos();
//              break;
//      case 4: display();
//              break;
//      case 5: create();
//              break;
        default: cout<<"Wrong Choice\n";
    }
    cout<<"Do you wish to continue? Y/N \n";
    cin>>n;
    }
    while(n!='n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can narrow down the problem by removing unnecessary code until only the very smallest program remains that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: No, it does not work fine with creating a linked list, `a->next=NULL` - the pointer `a` is uinitialized. What does it mean that you can't debug?

Comment: I can see a `new` but no `delete`. That's a memory leak. The function `display` has return type `node *` but there is no return statement.

Comment: I guess I got it, S.M. clarifies what actually might be going wrong with code. I'll try to run it now.

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need `typedef struct`; remove the `typedef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix most of the problems in your code

- You are allocating memory but you don't delete it. Use smart pointers
- Your function has a return type but doesn't return.
- Don't use cstrings. Use strings
- Don't dereference uninitialised pointers.
- Don't use `NULL`. Use either `nullptr` or remove it completely.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct node {
    std::string name;
    int rollno;
    std::unique_ptr<node> next;
};

void create(std::unique_ptr<node> &first)
{
    std::unique_ptr<node> newnode = std::make_unique<node>();
    std::cout << "--------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "Enter Student Information\n";
    std::cout << "Name- \t";
    std::cin >> newnode->name;
    std::cout << "Roll No- ";
    std::cin >> newnode->rollno;
    std::cout << "--------------------------\n";
    if (!first)
        first = std::move(newnode);
    else {
        auto a = first.get();
        while (a->next)
            a = a->next.get();
        a->next = std::move(newnode);
    }
}

void display(const std::unique_ptr<node> &first)
{
    if (!first)
        std::cout << "Empty List\n";
    else {
        auto temp = first.get();
        while (temp) {
            std::cout << "Student Information\n";
            std::cout << "--------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "Name- ";
            std::cout << temp->name;
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << "Roll No- ";
            std::cout << temp->rollno;
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << "--------------------------\n";
            temp = temp->next.get();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<node> first;
    char n;
    int ch;
    do {
        std::cout << "--------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Enter your choice\n";
        std::cout << "1>Create LL\n2>Display\n";
        std::cout << "--------------------------\n";
        std::cin >> ch;
        switch (ch) {
        case 1:
            create(first);
            break;
        case 2:
            display(first);
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Wrong Choice\n";
        }
        std::cout << "Do you wish to continue? Y/N \n";
        std::cin >> n;
    } while (n != 'n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes this solves my problem, thank you for clearly pointing the errors with solution :)